# How to display a customized (with JAVASCRIPT) htm page in a python GUI made with WEBKIT and GTK

Tags: javascript, webkit, pygtk

I'd like to load and display an html page using gtk and webkit. Here is what I have done so far:

[load an html page, change its look (via JAVASCRIPT) and display it in a PYGTK GUI using WEBKIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079966/load-an-html-page-change-its-look-and-display-it-in-a-pygtk-gui)

The problem is that I'd like to customize the the look of this page by taking away some divs.

Could somebody please point me to the right direction.

thank you
Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question.

The solution to this problem is actually suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748404/python-gtk-webkit-insert-javascript-after-gtk-main/11774423#11774423) and it is possible via the use of the webkit method `execute_script` and the code could be (untested and incomplete code):

```
import gtk
import webkit

def load_finished(b):
    js = 'alert("a");'
    b.execute_script(js)


w = gtk.Window()
b = webkit.WebView()
w.add(b)
b.open('http://example.com')
w.show_all()

b.connect("load-finished", load_finished)

gtk.main()
```

A completed solution (which is also the one implemented by me) is available here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import gtk, webkit
# import jswebkit

# set of methods for the browser
def delete_event(widget, event, data=None):
    return False

def destroy(widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

def go_back(widget, data=None):
    browser.go_back()

def go_forward(widget, data=None):
    browser.go_forward()

def go_home(widget, data=None):
    browser.open("http://opencores.org/projects")

def load_www(widge, url):
    try:
        url.index("://")
    except:
        url = "http://" + url
    www_adr_bar.set_text(url)
    browser.open(url)

def load_www_bar(widge):    
    url = www_adr_bar.get_text()
    load_www(widge, url)

def update_buttons(widget, data=None):
    www_adr_bar.set_text( widget.get_main_frame().get_uri() )
    back_button.set_sensitive(browser.can_go_back())
    forward_button.set_sensitive(browser.can_go_forward())

def load_progress_amount(webview, amount):
    progress.set_fraction(amount/100.0)

    js_code = """
        var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0]; 
        if (el1) el1.parentNode.removeChild(el1);

        var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName("banner")[0]; 
        if (el2) el2.parentNode.removeChild(el2);

        var el3 = document.getElementsByClassName("line")[0]; 
        if (el3) el3.parentNode.removeChild(el3);

        var el4 = document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0]; 
        if (el4) el4.parentNode.removeChild(el4);

        var el5 = document.getElementsByClassName("mainmenu")[0]; 
        if (el5) el5.parentNode.removeChild(el5);

        var el6 = document.getElementsByClassName("pad_leftside")[0]; 
        if (el6) el6.parentNode.removeChild(el6);

        var el7 = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-tools")[0]; 
        if (el7) el7.parentNode.removeChild(el7);

        var el8 = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
        if (el8){ var el81 = el8.nextElementSibling
                  if (el81 != null) el81.parentNode.removeChild(el81); }

        d1 = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
        if(d1){d1.style.width="100%";
               d1.style.margin="0pt";}

        d2 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        if(d2) d2.style.backgroundColor= "#FFF";

        d3 = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
        if (d3) {d3.style.width="100%";
                 d3.style.paddingBottom ="20pt";}

        function getsupportedprop(proparray){
            var root=document.documentElement
            for (var i=0; i<proparray.length; i++){
                if (typeof root.style[proparray[i]]=="string"){
                    return proparray[i] 
        }}}

        // change some css3 proprieties 
        var boxshadowprop=getsupportedprop(['boxShadow', 'MozBoxShadow', 'WebkitBoxShadow'])
        d4 = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
        if(d4) d4.style[boxshadowprop]='0px 0px 0px #FFF';
    """
    try:
        pass
        webview.execute_script(js_code)
        #ctx = get_js_context(webview)
        #ctx.EvaluateScript(js_code)
    except:
        pass

def load_started(webview, frame):
    progress.set_visible(True)

#def get_js_context(webview):
#    frame = webview.get_main_frame()
#    return jswebkit.JSContext(frame.get_global_context())

def load_finished(webview, frame):
    progress.set_visible(False)

def download(webview, download):

    import threading, urllib

    saveas = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=None,
             action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE,
             buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                      gtk.STOCK_SAVE, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

    # get url under the mouse and propose it as file name
    downloadfrom = download.get_network_request().get_uri()
    saveas.set_current_name(downloadfrom.split('/')[-1]) # better stripping method is needed

    saveas.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
    resp = saveas.run()

    if resp == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        downloadto = saveas.get_filename()
    saveas.destroy()

    if resp == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        # TODO this needs to go in a different thread
        # also, this will not work with the link: http://opencores.org/download,audio
        print 'Downloading: ', downloadfrom, 'and saving it in:', downloadto

        #urllib.urlretrieve(downloadfrom, downloadto)

        # multithreading version
        mythread = threading.Thread(target = urllib.urlretrieve,
                                   args = (downloadfrom,downloadto))
        mythread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    win.set_size_request(920, 600)
    win.connect("delete_event", delete_event)
    win.connect("destroy", destroy)
    win.set_resizable(True)

    scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    browser = webkit.WebView()

    settings = browser.get_settings()
    settings.set_property('enable-default-context-menu', True)


    browser.connect("load-progress-changed", load_progress_amount)
    browser.connect("load-started", load_started)
    browser.connect("load-finished", load_finished)
    browser.connect("load_committed", update_buttons)
    #browser.connect("download-requested", download_link)
    browser.connect("download_requested", download)

    prj_button = gtk.Button('OpenCores')
    login_button = gtk.Button('Login')
    account_button = gtk.Button('My Account')
    faq_button = gtk.Button('FAQ')

    prj_button.connect("clicked", load_www,'http://opencores.org/projects')
    login_button.connect("clicked", load_www,'http://opencores.org/login')
    account_button.connect("clicked", load_www,'http://opencores.org/acc')
    faq_button.connect("clicked", load_www,'http://opencores.org/faq')

    www_adr_bar = gtk.Entry()
    www_adr_bar.connect("activate", load_www_bar)
    hlp_hbox = gtk.HBox()
    hlp_vbox = gtk.VBox()
    progress = gtk.ProgressBar()
    back_button = gtk.ToolButton(gtk.STOCK_GO_BACK)
    back_button.connect("clicked", go_back)
    forward_button = gtk.ToolButton(gtk.STOCK_GO_FORWARD)
    forward_button.connect("clicked", go_forward)
    #home_button = gtk.ToolButton(gtk.STOCK_HOME)
    #home_button.connect("clicked", go_home)

    # put stuff together
    hlp_hbox.pack_start(back_button,False, False,5)
    hlp_hbox.pack_start(forward_button,False, False)
    #hlp_hbox.pack_start(home_button,False, False)

    hlp_hbox.pack_start(prj_button,False, False,4)
    hlp_hbox.pack_start(login_button,False, False,4)
    hlp_hbox.pack_start(account_button,False, False,4)
    hlp_hbox.pack_start(faq_button,False, False,4)

    hlp_hbox.pack_start(www_adr_bar,True, True,4)

    hlp_vbox.pack_start(hlp_hbox,False, False,2)
    hlp_vbox.pack_start(scroller,True, True,4)
    hlp_vbox.pack_start(progress,False, False)
    scroller.add(browser)

    default_www = 'http://opencores.org/projects'
    www_adr_bar.set_text(default_www)

    # LOAD PAGE
    browser.open(default_www)
    back_button.set_sensitive(False)
    forward_button.set_sensitive(False)

    win.add(hlp_vbox)
    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

This will produce the following result:

[image]

where without the command `webview.execute_script(js_code)` the effect would be:

[image]