# Python GTK + webkit - insert JavaScript after gtk.main()

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I tried this in terminal and everything is OK, but if I run this inside script I can not insert JavaScript after gtk.main()

```
import gtk
import webkit

w = gtk.Window()
b = webkit.WebView()
w.add(b)
b.open('http://example.com')
w.show_all()

gtk.main() # this I don`t run inside terminal

#and after showing window I want to insert some JavaScript code

js = 'alert("a");'
b.execute_script(js)
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Well, this problem is actually quite classic in GUI programming and so it is the solution. Direct actions (e.g. press a button) as well as indirect actions (webkit browser finishing loading a page) need always to fire up actions (functions) that sit on different processes or different threads.

In this case you can use the `"load-finished"` event given by the `webkit` object `b`.

Once the web page has completed loading the associated function will fire up executing your JS code. This is what the code looks like:

```
def load_finished(webview, frame):
    js = 'alert("a");'
    b.execute_script(js)

b = webkit.WebView()
b.connect("load-finished", load_finished)
```

Comment: Closely followed by gtk.main().  Good answer with example.

Comment: Fabrizio, thanks! This works if I want to insert js in document. What to do if there is JavaScript code e.g. body onload? 
With load-finished event default js functions are executed after inserted js. In this example first js will bi alert('a') and after that on body on load.
Probably I need callback approach which is suggested by James Hurford but my Python knowledge is not so good. .. probably I have to implement threading and callback ...
Thanks againt to both of you.

Comment: Or you could use a timer, I believe gtk comes with one, or it could be in glib  This will avoid the concurrency problems you may have with threads.  It really depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

gtk.main() will block until it receives a gtk.main_quit() is called or some other similar exit call.  Afraid you'll have to do all javascript insertions using either callbacks or before you call gtk.main().

Surprised you managed to run gtk.main() without it blocking until you hit Ctrl+C in the terminal.